# Express not receiving jquery post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, post

I used an express server and jquery on the client side. I send a post request to the server through jquery post method but it doesn't even get registered on the server.

Here's the relevant server code:

```html
var express=require("express");
var path=require("path");
var bodyParser=require("body-parser");
var app=express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
})); 
app.post("/tru",function(req,res){
console.log("Ok done"); //This never gets logged.
console.log(req.body.messag);
});
```

And here's the client code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="sef"><input id="ae" placeholder="Enter Something"></form>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#sef").submit(function(){
$.post("localhost:3000/tru",{messag:$("#ae").val()});
});
});

</script>
```

So, what is the error?

Edit- Solved the problem. Just change the $post method to:

```
se=$("#ae").val();
$.post("/tru",{messag:se});
```

Apparently, jquery doesn't recognize localhost.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try with `$("#sef").on("submit"...`

Comment: Also `$.post("/tru")`

Comment: yes, you're right.

Comment: Is the server side code complete? Because you do not have properly setup server yet.

Comment: @Tolsee Yes, the server is complete. This is only the part of the server code relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the server to listen on port 3000.

```
app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Server listen on 3000');
});
```

Comment: Yes. The server also sends the index.html file so the server is surely running at 3000